# Filter Pandas DataFrames Using Dynamic URL Query String

Tags: python, pandas

Currently i am having an question in python pandas. I want to filter a dataframe using url query string dynamically.

For eg: 
CSV:

[image]

url: http://example.com/filter?Name=Sam&Age=21&Gender=male

**Hardcoded**:

```
filtered_data = data[
    (data['Name'] == 'Sam') &
    (data['Age'] == 21) &
    (data['Gender'] == 'male') 
];
```

I don't want to hard code the filter keys like before because the csv file changes anytime with different column headers.
Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, your web framework will return the arguments in a dict-like structure. Let's say your args are like this:

```
args = {
    'Name': ['Sam'],
    'Age': ['21'],         # Note that Age is a string
    'Gender': ['male']
}
```

You can filter your dataset successively like this:

```
for key, values in args.items():
    data = data[data[key].isin(values)]
```

However, this is likely not to match any data for `Age`, which may have been loaded as an integer. In that case, you could load the CSV file as a string via `pd.read_csv(filename, dtype=object)`, or convert to string before comparison:

```
for key, values in args.items():
    data = data[data[key].astype(str).isin(values)]
```

Incidentally, this will also match multiple values. For example, take the URL http://example.com/filter?Name=Sam&Name=Ben&Age=21&Gender=male -- which leads to the structure:

```
args = {
    'Name': ['Sam', 'Ben'],    # There are 2 names
    'Age': ['21'],
    'Gender': ['male']
}
```

In this case, both Ben and Sam will be matched, since we're using `.isin` to match.

Comment: A note, here would be, to read all data as strings, or know the `type` of each columns. eg `Age`

Comment: Is there any reason why you converted your answer to a community wiki?

Comment: Saved my time @S Anand :) Thank you. Filters are working as expected

Comment: @EdChum -- just in case anyone wanted to contribute further to the answer. Any guidelines I should follow on when to make something a community wiki?

Comment: Really wikis are for a different thing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/when-to-mark-the-community-wiki-checkbox-on-a-new-question others can suggest edits to your answer to improve it but your suggestion is not what the community wiki is for in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to create this filter dynamically is probably to use `np.all`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

query = {'Name': 'Sam', 'Age': 21, 'Gender': 'male'}
filters = [data[k] == v for k, v in query.items()]
filter_data = data[np.all(filters, axis=0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

use `df.query`. For example

```
df = pd.read_csv(url)
conditions = "Name == 'Sam' and Age == 21 and Gender == 'Male'"
filtered_data = df.query(conditions)
```

You can build the conditions string dynamically using string formatting like

```
conditions = " and ".join("{} == {}".format(col, val) 
                           for col, val in zip(df.columns, values)
```